# QGIS CRS problems

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Are there any known CRS bugs in QGIS 3.10 or 3.14 ?

This is just ONE example of MANY problems I had the last months with CRS in QGIS: I have a layer for Germany which has CRS 25832. Sometimes it is shown in the south of France. But only sometimes.

When I restart QGIS everything is fine again. Sometimes I have even to reboot my PC in order to get rid of the CRS weirdness.

Operating system: Windows 10
QGIS Versions: 3.10 and 3.14
PROJ: 6.3.2
GDAL/OGR: 3.0.4
The layer is stored in a geopackage.
The layer is added to the project via drag & drop from browser panel.
The problem persists when I work with a new profile.

The problem:
[image]

The same layer in ArcGIS - it seems to be correct:
[image]

After closing and restarting QGIS, the layer is shown at the right position
[image]

[image]
After a few minutes, the problem comes back. Also with a new user profile and other layers.

You can check the data here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/19RJ9ScdpfnklY3heIqoBJJTNDvl7jacD/view?usp=sharing

EDIT 15.7.2020:

As you suggest I use 3857 as a project CRS and a different basemap. The layers are shown near france. I added another raster layer which should be in 3853 like the two layers I added here for download. With 3857 as project CRS the raster layer shows up in Germany. With 25832 it shows up in France, but at least consistent with the other two layers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what the operating systems is? how you add the layer? how it is stored? does it have a valid projection set (check with ogrinfo)? did you select a transformation? did you delete the required grid file after you selected the transformation? does it still occur with a new profile?

Comment: What is your data source? Shape file, GeoPackage, PostGIS, ...?

Comment: I updated my above post. The data source is geopackage. I don't know how to use ogrinfo. I did not select a transformation.

Comment: I reported the QGIS issue on Gíthub: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37809 Lets see what comes out of it.

Comment: sounds like a bug indeed. If you look at the faulty screen-shot, the basemap is not in 25832 but likely in plain 3857 (in 25832, the images are distorted). Moreover, it seems some caching is occurring as the polygons "jump" from the good/bad location when playing with the zoom level. Also when the polygons are at the bad location, if you pan the map slowly, you can see the base map jump for a huge distance (like 200-300km instead of a few 10's)

Comment: You may want to try with a different basemap. Maybe it is OSM that fails to return the proper tiles under this projection

Comment: You have to configure the OpenStreetMap with the Google projection (Epsg:3857), right-click -> properties -> source -> select EPSG:3857, with this you can see your map in right way.

Comment: Did you try a basemap from QuickMapsServices Plugin?

Comment: I tried with different basemaps, also with QuickMapServices Plugin. The problem keeps coming back no matter which basemap. Sometimes it happens exactly as JGH describes. I will work with 3857 today. As soon as the problem comes back I will post here.

Comment: Problem keeps coming back. I edited the post above and added two new screenshots.