# QGIS WMS layer alignment with OSM

Tags: qgis, wms, alignment, client

Please bear with as I'm a complete novice when it comes to GIS and QGIS, so some of the terminology may be incorrect.

I am using QGIS as a WMS client to test my WMS server. I am trying to overlay a radar image generated by the server over an OSM map, but am having alignment problems. The layer capabilities are shown below

```
 <Layer>
  <Name>Layer</Name>
  <Title>Radar</Title>
  <CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
  <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    <westBoundLongitude>-3.945963</westBoundLongitude>
    <eastBoundLongitude>-2.564137</eastBoundLongitude>
    <southBoundLatitude>53.229555</southBoundLatitude>
    <northBoundLatitude>53.666227</northBoundLatitude>
  </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
  <BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-3.945963" miny="53.229555" maxx="-2.564137" maxy="53.666227"/>
</Layer>
```

The image produced is projected using a transverse projection (WGS84 UTM zone 30N).
The QGIS project has its projection set to the same projection EPSG:32630. Picture below showing the problem

[image]

I have tested this using UDIG and the alignment is spot on
[image]

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Regards

Comment: Does the WMS only support CRS:84?  Can you also add EPSG:3857, EPSG:4326 and EPSG:32630

Comment: I'm pretty sure that qgis automatically changes the projection when you add OSM

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply - at present the server only supports CRS84 - its written in C++, so I would have to code support for the conversion from metres to lalong - the server renderer requires the bbox to be in degrees

Comment: Why would adding support for these extra CRS make any difference to the alignment problem?

Comment: see this related [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367711/qgis-crs-problems) comments.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that post, but I'm still unsure what I should do to resolve my alignment issue

Comment: The reason for suggesting the different supported CRS was to test whether the services/data are in the actual CRS you think them to be in.   Not sure why udig gets it right but qgis not.  Can you look at the network traffic and see what actual requests are made

Comment: Yep - I can easily see the network traffic as I have written the server and renderer - the renderer creates a transverse mercator projected radar image from the raw radar data. The renderer also allows has a direct tcp connection from our display system which alows us to render the radar image over a  nautical chart which uses the same projection as the radar image, and this has no alignment issues

Comment: I was thinking as much about the requests to OSM

Comment: There is the QGIS network logger - does that help?

Comment: I have tried other base maps and still get the same misalignment with these settings
base map crs 3857, my map crs wgs84(crs84) and project crs 3857